# ReactJS setState only works when nested inside setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The issue:
When I use this.setState and I output the state in the callback, it doesn't change at all but when I nest the setstate inside a setstate it will then work correctly.

Example:
This doesn't work -

```
this.setState({
    data: newData
});
```

This does work -

```
this.setState({
    data: newData
}, () => {
    this.setState({
        data: newData
    });
});
```

Does this have something to do with the way react batches state updates?

This is the actual code in which the setstate doesn't work unless I nest it (I've tried commenting everything out in this function and using setState to set coursePage to null but it doesn't work unless it's nested):

```
cancelCPIndexChange(index){
  let temp = this.state.coursePages;
  this.hideEditingCoursePage(index);
  let canceledIndex = temp[index];
  temp = temp.slice(0, index).concat(temp.slice(index+1));
  temp = temp.slice(0, parseInt(canceledIndex.course_pageindex)-1).concat(canceledIndex).concat(temp.slice(parseInt(canceledIndex.course_pageindex)-1));
  this.setState({
    coursePages: temp
  }, () => {this.setState({
      coursePages: temp
    });
  });
}
```

This is another function on the same level as cancelCPIndexChanges that is able to modify the state of coursePages:

```
showEditingCoursePage(index){
  let temp = this.state.coursePages;
  temp[index].editingCoursePage = true;
  this.setState({
    coursePages: temp
  });    
}
```

These functions are in course.js. Both these functions are passed down to CoursePages.js and then to CoursePage.js.

Comment: No, `this.setState` always works. Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: How do you call set state? It might be a "this" scope issue.

Comment: I doubt I can replicate the issue in fiddle. The other functions on the same scope level that use setState work just fine except for this particular function. I've binded the function at the correct level too.

Comment: Unless you are confident that something besides `setState` is causing the issue, I don't see how you can be confident you wont be able to reproduce it in a fiddle. And if thats the case, we wont be able to help you without seeing the code you think is causing the issue.

Comment: I've updated my post with more information... hopefully there's more clues for you guys.

Comment: @Recur did you figure this out in the end? – I have the same problem, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

According to: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

`setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.`

(I've noticed this myself in the past)

I'm not 100% certain, but I'd guess that the second `setState` in your callback function is "flushing" the pending state transition before creating the second one.

I'm not clear on where you want to consume the new value of state? It ought to be in the `render` method where you can be sure it's been updated (As the state transition triggers the render). If you want to use it immediately after the `setState` you still have the reference to the value, so can use that directly.

Comment: I working under the assumption that setState automatically updates the view after it's done setting the state.

When I print out the state in the callback of the first setState it's the old data.

Comment: The state transition triggers `render()` and updates the view. As the doc says, that doesn't necessarily occur right away after you call `setState()`. It does sound like it's do with batching, as you suspected.

Comment: @Recur Always assume that `setState` is an asynchronous call, and you'll be good.
If you want to call other functions synchronously, based on the value you are setting, then call them and pass the value in as an argument. If you want to asynchronously call other methods, after you know the state has been set, then call them from inside the callback (and as a personal preference, I would still pass the value in as an argument). The state will be updated by the time `render` is called again, on your behalf, but if you're doing other things, assume setState is async; it will save you headaches.

Comment: @MattHolland It's more likely that @Recur is logging after `setState` (which returns the previous value), and failing to get the appropriate result, inside of the `setState` callback, he's duplicating the call to `setState`, and logging immediately after the second call, which gets him the *first* value he sets (which just so happens to be equivalent to the second). If @Recur was to also add labels to each console log, and set three unique values, in-scope, and within the callback of each `setState`, each one should log appropriately (on next-tick callback).

Comment: @Norguard, yes I guess that there is only one pending state transition at any point. Calling setState a second time causes the existing one to be applied before creating the new one.

Comment: @MattHolland and even then, if you're calling `setState` from within the callback which is run *after* a successful setting of the same property, then your code is always going to be sequential, regardless of whether it's happening in the same callstack.

Answer (score 1):

As said setState behaves asynchronously.  There are two ways you can access the newly updated state value before render

1. Using a call back function for setState method
2. Use componentDidUpdate method.  Using nextState param you can access the latest state.  But make sure you should use setState method inside that

Comment: doesn't setState inside componentDidUpdate() create infinite loop of rendering component?

Comment: Sorry for unrelated question, in componentDidUpdate(), there has to be a if statement to avoid infinite loop.